# How to make video call programmatically on Android 2.2 or higher?

Tags: android, video, android-intent, video-conferencing

I am working on an application where I want to make a video call programmatically. I am using API level 8 for my application.

I have Samsung Galaxy S, where I can use video calling functionality. Using intent action **ACTION_CALL**, I can start voice call.

How to start video call? Which intent extra I have to provide? Is there any particular field which indicates that current outgoing call is video call? If yes, how can I set that field to indicate that I want to invoke a video call?

Comment: Hi All,
I have searched different forums to solve my problem. I have found that Galaxy S allows us to place video call in a normal way. I have seen, whenever I place a voice call, value for **"com.phone.extra.calltype"** field will be set to "1" and for video call its value will be set to "2".

This is the only difference that I have found. Is it possible to set **"com.phone.extra.calltype"** field to indicate new call is a video call? If yes, how can I set **"com.phone.extra.calltype"** extra field, while placing new call intent? Please help me. Any help will be grateful to me. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for creating video call on my Samsung Galaxy Tab (Android 2.2)

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall");
callIntent.putExtra("videocall", true);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + [your number goes here]));
activity.startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Hello Alekz, I am getting  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.phone.videocall dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx (has extras) }. can you please help me. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli Hi. That solution is device specific. Your exeption mean that your device does not have requested package/activity. The only thing I can advise is to make a video call from your actual device and to look through the logcat. Maybe you will be able to make some sort of reverse engeneering (that was what I did for my Galaxy Tab)

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli Try adding intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: How to set Time limit for the video calling

Comment: how directly make a vidoe call for google duo to particular phone no provided here callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + [your number goes here])); with out display that apps main screen.