# Make voice and video call through internet with our application?

Tags: android, voip, video-conferencing

I want to develop *voice and video call* through **our application users** in android like Wechat Application. How can i doing this? 
I have searched in Google but i didn't get any exact reference or samples. Can anyone explain and give some sample source and references for doing this functionality? 
And I have few confusion about SIP and VOIP which one im going to use for support android versions 2.2 to higher versions applications?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7231397/1396082) link

Comment: U want to have a voice call using internet?

Comment: @Wishy S do you have any idea about that

Comment: as far as I know karthik voice calling through internet is done using VOIP (Voice over internet packet)...for this you need to develop a dialer through which you can make a call to specific id'd or number...You will have to assign a unique id to every device in which you will be installing the application

Comment: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

Comment: Have a look over this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511372/voip-library-for-android

Comment: hi Mr @NightCrawler i m not asking video call through phone?

Comment: @Wishy once i gone through those links if i update you?

Comment: @Wishy i have gone through those references, and i got some idea how can i use IMSDroid in my application can you please guide me?

Comment: @Karthik sorry man...but i have not worked on this kind of application yet...as it is still in the pipeline at my workplace...though still i will let you know if i find something more useful

Comment: http://www.predictive-dialer.org/predictive-dialer-blog/?p=38 will help to clear doubt SIP Vs VOIP.

Comment: This question is too broad; [questions asking only for generic examples are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291259/2747593). Instead, start writing code, and come back when you have a more specific problem. Be sure to show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 16):

[Lumincall](https://github.com/opentelecoms-org/lumicall) is an open source SIP. its under GPL licence so you wont Have to pay for it.

[Linphone](https://github.com/dmonakhov/linphone-android) is an open source Voice Over IP.its also nder GPL licence so you wont Have to pay for it.
you can get the source code of these app. it may help you

Answer (score 10):

> You can use ***Jingle*** for video calling. voice call can also be done using jingle. But mostly in Android, SIP Protocol is used for voice calling since it is comes with android.

[Voice call over SIP Protocol](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)

> You can also look into this sample implementation of SIP in Android.

[SIP Protocol Implemetation](http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/)

> You can find some Jingle Documentations here

[Jingle Specifications link](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create socket communication over your server.(Leave stream) I development basicly two years ago. I send computer's camera views to phone screen via internet before. (Real time video stream)

Comment: Hi nurisezgin please give me hint how can i achieve same that you have develop because i want to do same and it's my university final project. Thanks

Comment: Hi Devani, this link maybe helpfull for you --->   http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html