# Implementing Voice/Video Chat Application in android

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip, videochat

my new task is to implement Voice/Video chat native application in Android. I browsed net for the same and it was written that using Android "SIP" API we can do it. I gone through the documents about SIP.In Implementing using SIP we required SIP address for each user which will be provided by different SIP providers. I also checked the SipDemo sample app provided in samples.

Problem is my app will be used by many Users and they can chat with any others.

**So, how can we generate  SIP address for each user dynamically and establish communication session ?**

or each there any other way of doing this ?

Please Help

Comment: Have you developed a simple chat app with media share?? What library and server you used?

Comment: @Shink : No i haven't developed any chat app, in fact this is the first time i am working on a project like this. Can you through some light on Media Share ?

Comment: Media share: image , audio , video or any file sharing with the users

Comment: @Shink : Thanks for your reply. Is Media share is an Android API  (or) any library . Please let me know how to use it. Sharing Links for the same will be helpful

Comment: For chat you need to create a server like Openfire and you can use Asmack client for the chat app. File share comes inbuilt in Asmack.

Comment: download smack from here   https://igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp

Comment: @Shink : i want to implement Voice / Video Chat App . Text Chat is not required. Can you guide me in implementing it

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910700/make-voice-and-video-call-through-internet-with-our-application

Comment: @Shink: i gone through this Url earlier. i decided to use SIP for voice chat . As mentioned in my question  i confused with SIP address and raised this question. Can you once again go through my question and help me. Also, i am newbie to Stack over flow . Is it ok to continue this conversation in Comments ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your android app you can generate a free sip account from [AntiSip](https://www.antisip.com/sip-antisip-com-register).

and for generating sip account dynamically you have to configure sip on your server with the help of [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/):

Answer (score 0):

Two VoIP software can contact each other directly by using direct SIP URI like username@IP:port.

This can work fine on local networks where the UA (sip user agent) has fix address. Otherwise you will need to use a SIP server (This is the main role of a SIP registrar server: to keep a track of the user locations). There are plenty open source software for this like the above mentioned Asterisk but you can also find a lot of services offering free calls (free from softphone to softphone; they charge only if you wish to make outbound calls to landline or mobile numbers).