# Android video call programmatically

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdk-tools

I would like to know is it possible to make a video call in android programmatically? I found this question ([How to make video call programmatically on Android 2.2 or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121623/how-to-make-video-call-programmatically-on-android-2-2-or-higher)) but the answer seems to be only for Samsung phone. 
 Is there any other solution without using any Api?
Want through 3g/4g. Like the regular video call feature a mobile phone has.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make voice and video call through internet with our application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910700/make-voice-and-video-call-through-internet-with-our-application)

Comment: i dont want to use internet services. Just the native video call

Comment: so you mean through the LAN ? or you want to call through the 3G / 4G network another telephone number with video ?

Comment: I want through 3g/4g. Like the regular video call feature a mobile phone has

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using XMPP. You can find more details about it [here](http://xmpp.org/about/technology-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know perfect about SIP - Session Initiation Protocol but using this it will be possible.