# How do I make a video call?

Tags: android, video

This becomes a voice call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:01012345678")); 
intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_START_CALL_WITH_VIDEO_STATE,VideoProfile.STATE_BIDIRECTIONAL);
```

How do I make a video call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make video call programmatically on Android 2.2 or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121623/how-to-make-video-call-programmatically-on-android-2-2-or-higher)

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent videocall= new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall");
videocall.putExtra("videocall", true);
videocall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + [your number]));
activity.startActivity(videocall);
```