# How do I make a video call using Intent in android

Tags: android, kotlin, call

I want to make video call directly but this code is not working.
please halp me.

```kotlin
 val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL).apply {
      data = Uri.parse("tel:" + "PHONE_NUMBER")
      putExtra("videocall", true)
    }
 startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Did you tried this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43409738/10954249

Comment: @DeePanShu Thank you for answering this question. But It is not working for me..

Comment: Is there any installed app that can handle this intent action on your device?

Comment: @DeePanShu I just want to use basic video call app like when use `startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "PHONE_NUMBER))`, this code call the basic(=default) voice call app.

Comment: Which app do you want to use as a Basic app? Is it installed on your device??

Comment: @DeePanShu Yes!! The Basic App means (I said) is already installed on my device when I bought it.

Comment: Can you share me the name of that basic app and the device model??

Comment: @DeePanShu Yes. My testPhone is Z flip 3 on SAMSUNG and basic app's name is 'Phone'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
data = Uri.parse("tel:" + "PHONE_NUMBER")

val videoCall = Intent("com.android.phone.videocall")
videoCall.putExtra("videoCall", true)
videoCall.setData(data)
startActivity(videocall)
```

I hope it's working.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. But It is not working for me.. I try to change `videocall` to `videoCall`, but it's same error like this -> `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.phone.videoCall dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxx (has extras) }`

Comment: Wrap it with try catch block.,it can help you something.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Intent` object to this

```
Intent("com.android.phone.videocall")
```

instead of `Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)`

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. But It is not working for me...